# accordion functionality in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap accordion in my project. I added plus/minus symbols for heading. The clicking functionality should apply only for heading of the accordion group. But in my program it is applying for entire panel-group of accordion. So, If I click on any part of the panel-body the functionality is working. How can change this?

My js code:

```js
$scope.changeIcon = function (index) {
  if($scope.plus[index]=='+ ') {
    $scope.plus[index] = '- ';
  }
  else {

    $scope.plus[index] = '+ ';
  }
};
```

```html
My HTML code:

<uib-accordion close-others="oneAtATime" class="accordion-data">
   <uib-accordion-group heading="{{plus[$index]}}{{area.areaname}}" ng-repeat="area in areas track by area.areaname" ng-click="changeIcon($index)">
           
  /* Some other stuff */            
              
</uib-accordion-group>
</uib-accordion
```

Comment: Can someone please respond for this question? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Protip: If you include a fiddle or plunker of your problem, people are likely to respond quicker and more surely :)

Anyway, you can use the `<uib-accordion-heading>` element to specify a customized heading, and then attach the `ng-click` to a `<span>` element inside the heading; this way it will only be called when the text is clicked.

Fiddle as an example. It's using an old version of ui-bootstrap, but it's basically just the same in your case, just swap `<accordion-heading>` --> `<uib-accordion-heading>`.

http://jsfiddle.net/68gk8/156/